# Swift CoreDataでリレーション先の集計値でソートしたい

Tags: swift, swiftui, coredata

リレーションを設定したCoreDataのエンティティ
`class`　学級
`student` 学生
があります。

classには、studentsと言う名前でTo Manyのリレーションをstudentに対して設定します。

studentにはbirthdayと言うAttributeがあるとして、
classをFetchする際に、studentのbirthdayでソートするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

つまり、クラスの中で一番早い誕生日の人の順にクラスを並べたいのです。

```
[クラス1]
 Aさん 2010/1/3 生まれ <--クラスの中で一番早い
 Bさん 2010/7/13 生まれ
 Cさん 2010/10/18 生まれ
```

```
[クラス2]
 Dさん 2010/6/10 生まれ <--クラスの中で一番早い
 Eさん 2010/8/25 生まれ
 Fさん 2010/12/7 生まれ
```

```
[クラス3]
 Gさん 2010/2/8 生まれ <--クラスの中で一番早い
 Hさん 2010/9/10 生まれ
 Iさん 2010/11/7 生まれ
```

と、あったとして

```
結果：一番誕生日が早い人だけを対象に並び替える
クラス1：Aさん 2010/1/3 生まれ 
クラス3：Gさん 2010/2/8 生まれ
クラス2：Dさん 2010/6/10 生まれ
```

と並べたいのです。
早生まれは考慮しなくて構いません。
また、各クラスで2番目以降に早く生まれた人も考慮しないで構いません。

以下の指定はクラッシュしてしまいます。

```
@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key:"@min.class.students.birthday", ascending: true)]
        )
```

また、class+CoreDataClass.swift に「そのクラス内で一番早い誕生日を返すコンピューテッドプロパティ」を作ることは出来ますが、NSSortDescriptorのkeyやkeyPathにコンピューテッドプロパティを指定することは出来ませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

StudentsをClassのstudentsに入れる(保存)際に、並び替えて入れておくか、もしくは、一番早い人を表示したいときに毎度取得するしかないと思います。

```swift
let fastestBirthdayStudents = classes.map { $0.students.sorted { $0.birthday < $1.birthday }.first }
```